# Servlet returns an empty page

Tags: java, servlets

I'm beginner in servlets. I have just create a hello world servlet following a tutorial but the page that I got is a blank page.

**Servlet class:**

```
public class Test extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<meta charset=\"utf-8\" />");
        out.println("<title>Test</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<p>page generated from servlet servlet.</p>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }
}
```

**web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.Test</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/toto</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I opened the page with this url: http://localhost:8080/testWeb/toto
I got an empty page with any returned  exception

Comment: Have you checked the server logs?

Comment: Did you check the console?

Comment: Everything is fine in the console.

Comment: Anything written on the logs? Besides, i would suggest you to create a jsp page and use the RequestDispatcher to forward the request to it rather then constructing the page inside the servlet.

Comment: I already tried it with this statement: 
this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher( "/WEB-INF/test.jsp").forward( request, response ); 
and I got the same result.

Comment: Hi i regenerated your code my side and its working perfectly fine..Try clearing browser history or recreate that project

Comment: strange!! 
the same web.xml?
is there something that I have to configure in apache tomcat?

Comment: throw new ServletException(); just to test if your code is getting executed or not.

Comment: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Answer (score 3):

Replace the word "public" from in front of the name of the method ("doGet") with "protected".  "doGet"'s scope is protected in the HttpServlet class (see https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#doGet%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29 ).  You can't expand the scope of an overridden method, only narrow it, so you have in effect created a second "doGet" method as far as the container is concerned, but with a public scope.  When it manages the incoming HTTP request, it delegates the GET to its default protected-scope "doGet" method, which of course returns nothing to the output stream.  So to truly override the protected "doGet", write:

```
protected void doGet( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<head>");
    out.println("<meta charset=\"utf-8\" />");
    out.println("<title>Test</title>");
    out.println("</head>");
    out.println("<body>");
    out.println("<p>page generated from servlet servlet.</p>");
    out.println("</body>");
    out.println("</html>");
}
```

Also, I suggest flushing the 'out' stream; add:

```
out.flush();
```

after all the println() statements.  The container is supposed to flush the stream at the end of the method but I have seen cases where at times, it doesn't do it (depends on what container you are using).  Just to be safe.